# Termcap not working in Debian 10

Tags: debian, less, termcap

I just installed a headless Debian server, so far with an old monitor for initial setup. While doing the initial configuration and setup, I noticed one "inconvenience" - less always keeps innards of closed file in my terminal. So far I have found how to "not clear" that info with less parameter -X. That is the opposite of what I want, as I understand.

So I read less uses some termcap to keep some initial view when starting and to return to it when exiting, thus not showing the opened and then closed files text after exiting. But that seems deprecated.

I have no variables like $LESS or others starting with that name.

How do I get less to return to previous view and remove the file contents from screen/terminal after exiting? Is there some config less uses?

Comment: It sounds like you want the "alternate screen" behaviour. Please mention what terminal emulator you're using (`xterm`, `gnome-terminal`, `konsole`, `putty`, etc). `screen` and `tmux` are also terminal emulators, and only the latter has the alternate screen enabled by default (afair). Also, what does `echo "$TERM"` say? Will this switch to the alternate screen and revert after to the cmdline after you press Enter? `tput smcup; echo huh?; read var; tput rmcup`

Comment: I have no desktop environment installed, just plain F1, F2, F3 etc., as I plan to have it completely headless. The plain old default virtual terminals.

Comment: There's no alternate screen on virtual terminals. Try installing something like `tmux` or `screen` (for the latter, you will need `altscreen on` in `~/.screenrc`)

Comment: Yes, tmux works as expected out of the box. Thank you!